# Hibernate 5.0 close connections

Tags: java, hibernate

I updated the Hibernate 4.3 to Hibernate 5.0 in my application, i updated the deprecated wasCommitted() and wasRolledBack() in my code to TransactionStatus.COMMITTED and TransactionStatus.ROLLED_BACK in my HibernateUtils, but when executing it, I am having the problem that close all transactions and i don't know why, this is the log (i have ojdbc v8):

```
*INFO ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-1 login.Loginin - LOGIN USER....... user1
DEBUG ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-1 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl - Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
DEBUG ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-1 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl - Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
DEBUG ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-1 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
DEBUG ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-1 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - rolling back
DEBUG ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-1 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl - Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
DEBUG ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-1 org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl - Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction*
```

**My hibernateUtils:**

```
package database.config;
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.resource.transaction.spi.TransactionStatus;

public class HibernateUtil implements Serializable {  
      
      
      
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
      
      private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadSession;
      private static final ThreadLocal<Transaction> threadTransaction;
      
      private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HibernateUtil.class);  
        
      static {
            
                  try{
                        log.info("Creating threadSession and threadTransaction...");
                        threadSession = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
                        threadTransaction = new ThreadLocal<Transaction>();
                        
                        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
                        
                        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                          .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
                        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
                
                      
                        }catch (HibernateException he) {
                              log.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + he);
                              throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
                        }
            
            }
            
          public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            
              return sessionFactory;
          }
          
          
          
          public static void openSession() {
            
            sessionFactory.openSession();
            
          }
          
          public static Session getSession() throws Exception{
            
            Session s =  (Session) threadSession.get();
            
                        
            
              try {
                 if (s == null || !s.isOpen()) {
                    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
                          log.info("Opening new Session for this thread - "  + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    }
                    s = sessionFactory.openSession();
                    threadSession.set(s);
                             }
                 else {
                    
                    
                    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                          log.debug("Using current session in this thread - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    }
                 }
              }
              catch (HibernateException ex) {
                 throw ex;
              }
              
//            if (s.isDirty()) {
//                
//                log.info("Session is Dirty");
//                      s.flush();
//                      s.clear();
//                }

              return s;
            
            
          }
          
          public static void beginTransaction()
                throws Exception
              {
                Transaction localTransaction = null;
                try
                {
                  
                  localTransaction = (Transaction)threadTransaction.get();
                  if (localTransaction == null)
                  {
                   getSession();
                    localTransaction = ((Session)threadSession.get()).beginTransaction();
                    threadTransaction.set(localTransaction);
                  }
                }
                catch (HibernateException localHibernateException)
                {
                  throw new Exception(localHibernateException);
                }
              }
              
              public static void commitTransaction() throws Exception
              {
                Transaction localTransaction = null;
                try
                {
                   getSession();
                  
                   localTransaction = (Transaction)threadTransaction.get();
                  
                  
                  
                  
                   if (localTransaction != null && !localTransaction.getStatus().isOneOf(TransactionStatus.COMMITTED, TransactionStatus.ROLLED_BACK)) {
                            localTransaction.commit();
                            threadTransaction.set(null);
                  }
                }
                catch (HibernateException localHibernateException)
                {
                  rollbackTransaction();
              
                }
              }
              

              
       public static void rollbackTransaction() throws Exception
              {
                Transaction localTransaction = null;
                try
                {
                   getSession();
                  localTransaction = (Transaction)threadTransaction.get();
                  threadTransaction.set(null);
                  if (localTransaction != null && !localTransaction.getStatus().isOneOf(TransactionStatus.COMMITTED, TransactionStatus.ROLLED_BACK)) {
                      localTransaction.rollback();
                      threadTransaction.set(null);
                  }
                }
                catch (HibernateException localHibernateException)
                {
                
                }
              
              }       
          
              public static void closeSession()
              {
                Session localSession = null;
                try
                {
                  localSession = (Session)threadSession.get();
                  threadSession.set(null);
                  if ((localSession != null) && (localSession.isOpen()))
                  {
                    try
                    {
                      localSession.flush();
                    }
                    catch (Exception localException1) {}
                    try
                    {
                      localSession.disconnect();
                    }
                    catch (Exception localException2) {}
                    try
                    {
                      localSession.close();
                
                          
                    }
                    catch (Exception localException3) {}
                  }
                }
                catch (HibernateException localHibernateException)
                {
                  localHibernateException.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
              
              
}
```